# Ignoring SSL certificate error leads to WebRequest status 406

Tags: c#, ssl, request, httprequest

I'm currently writing my own test application for an API, which has an own test application, which works just fine.

It ignores certificate errors using `System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };// Allow all SSL peer certificates (for testing only!)`

When I run their test app, it connects and registers just fine. However, when I try to connect with my application, I get the response code 406. The thing is, both applications are nearly the same.

The only real difference is, that I don't provide a GUI for providing the data needed for connecting, since I hardcode them (just for testing). I'm calling the same method, use a connect button and get this error code.

I have the source of the API right next to me, but I'm not allowed to publish it. Instead, I could send you the method that causes the error code:

```
public WWSVCC_Response RawHttpRequestBytes(string method, string path, WebHeaderCollection headers, dynamic body)
    {
        if (body != null && (body as byte[]) == null && (body as Dictionary<string, dynamic>) == null) throw (new Exception("Type of parameter \"body\" is invalid"));
        if (body != null && method == "GET") method = "PUT";
        byte[] bodyBytes = null;
        WebResponse res = null;
        try
        {
            string uri = ((SSL) ? "https" : "http") + "://" + Host + ":" + Port.ToString() + RootPath + path;
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
            req.Headers = headers;
            ((HttpWebRequest)req).UserAgent = "WWSVC .NET client";
            ((HttpWebRequest)req).Accept = "*/*";
            req.Method = method;
            req.Timeout = 10000;
            Stream rs;
            if (body != null)
            {
                bodyBytes = body as byte[];
                if (bodyBytes == null) bodyBytes = JsonObjectEncoder(body);
                req.ContentLength = bodyBytes.Length;
                req.ContentType = "application/json";
                rs = req.GetRequestStream();
                rs.Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
                rs.Close();
            }
            try
            {
                res = req.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                res = ex.Response;
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            rs = res.GetResponseStream();
            byte[] resBytes;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int red = 1;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                while (red > 0)
                {
                    red = rs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (red > 0) ms.Write(buffer, 0, red);
                }
                resBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
            rs.Close();
            WWSVCC_Response r = new WWSVCC_Response(this, (int)((HttpWebResponse)res).StatusCode, resBytes, null, null, headers, bodyBytes);
            LastResponse = r;
            return r;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            WWSVCC_Response r = new WWSVCC_Response(this, (res == null) ? 0 : (int)((HttpWebResponse)res).StatusCode, null, null, ex, headers, bodyBytes);
            LastResponse = r;
            return r;
        }
    }
```

At this point, I tried everything, that I know that could work. Disabling the "Ignore Certificate" workaround causes the request to fail, due to the server application being a test server with an invalid SSL certificate. The server app only works with SSL, since it works with confidental data.

Do you have any idea, what the problem is?

Comment: 406 is "not acceptable" which in general means, that the server could not find valid accept-headers in your request. Maybe the API does not allow accept-header `*/*` and you have to give a specific type. Thus, it successfully created a connection, but the server could not fulfill your request.

Comment: The `*/*` was added by me, because I tried to fix it. Removing it results in the same error.

EDIT: Additionaly to that, the test application they provide works with `*/*` in the Accept header

Comment: You'll have to consult the documentation for the api and check for the correct header information, or if you host it yourself you can try to debug your request and find where it fails.

Comment: Let me try to explain: The server application I'm using is running on my PC, where I code. However, the server application is configured already and in the best case, it gets distributed like that. The headers should be perfectly fine, because the test application provided by the software company, who wrote both server app and test app works just fine using the same information. You could say they're the same. Is there maybe a project setting which could cause this?

Comment: Obviously, the information the server receives is not the same. I don't think the project settings of a c# project can cause different headers to be sent via `WebRequest`. If you cannot debug your server, you could search the source for the position where error 406 is generated and find how the control flow gets there.

Comment: Just used the DHC plugin for Chrome to create the same request. It works flawless. What is this? x.x